# Regular expression capture group returning wrong result for slightly different text

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I'm trying to write a PCRE with a capture group that looks for numerical values within two strings.

Case A:

> There is/are 1 thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.

Case B:

> There is/are still 10 thread(s) that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.

I've written a regex that when run on case A returns "1", but for case B it returns the wrong result "still". How can I write one that will return "1" for A and "10" for B?

Here's what I have:

```
There\s+is.are\s+(?<threadNumber>[^\s]+)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add an optional `(?:\S+\s+)?` before the number part to match an optional "word" and only use `\d+` to match digits:

```
There\s+is.are\s+(?:\S+\s+)?(?<threadNumber>\d+)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQNyMz/1)

**Details**

- `There` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `is` - a literal substring
- `.` - any char but a line break char
- `are` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?:\S+\s+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?<threadNumber>\d+)` - 1 or more digits (Group "threadNumber").